# Gluing text to longtable

Tags: tables, positioning, longtable

I am an occasional LaTex user. My question relates to the use of longtable. If I understand the standard table constructs, then "tabular" defines the layout of the actual table grid with contents, and "table" creates an environment for the table that governs the placement and also contains the associated text, such as the caption, notes, etc. Now, as I understand it, "longtable" basically replaces "tablular," but it cannot be placed into a "table" environment.

I need some text that is associated with the table to print out immediately below it, and don't know who to force that:

```
\begin{center}
{\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{lr}
\caption{Probit estimates for household matching, Burundi, 2006}\\
\hline
      & \textbf{Public/WFP transfers} \\
\cline{2-2}
      & \textbf{dF/dX} \\
\cline{2-2}
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
      & \textbf{Public/WFP transfers} \\
\cline{2-2}
      & \textbf{dF/dX} \\
\cline{2-2}
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
\multirow{2}{*}{leave-out mean of beneficiaries h'hold in the PSU} & 0.7929*** \\
     & [0.0479] \\
\multirow{2}{*}{household size} & -0.0093** \\
      & [0.0037] \\
\multirow{2}{*}{h'hold head is female} & 0.0337 \\
      & [0.0300] \\
… MANY MORE ROWS
Number of observations  & 3203 \\
\% of correct predictions & 84.01 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}}
\end{center}
```

Immediately followed by:

```
Robust standard errors in brackets.\\
*** p<0.01, ** p<0.05, * p<0.1\\
Authors’ estimations using 2006 QUIBB survey.\\
\textbf{Note}: For the impact analysis, the sample is restricted to
 the relevant geographic area. i.e. only the PSU with at least one 
 household who have benefited from the WFP transfer
```

.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`longtable` environments do not float, so the text placed after the table in the source will be typeset after the table. Also a `center` environment has no affect on `longtable` (which technically is always full width).

As an alternative to just placing it after the table you can place it in a `\multicolumn` so it is aligned with the columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,longtable}
\begin{document}


{\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{lr}
\caption{Probit estimates for household matching, Burundi, 2006}\\
\hline
      & \textbf{Public/WFP transfers} \\
\cline{2-2}
      & \textbf{dF/dX} \\
\cline{2-2}
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
      & \textbf{Public/WFP transfers} \\
\cline{2-2}
      & \textbf{dF/dX} \\
\cline{2-2}
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
\multirow{2}{*}{leave-out mean of beneficiaries h'hold in the PSU} & 0.7929*** \\
     & [0.0479] \\
\multirow{2}{*}{household size} & -0.0093** \\
      & [0.0037] \\
\multirow{2}{*}{h'hold head is female} & 0.0337 \\
      & [0.0300] \\
… MANY MORE ROWS
Number of observations  & 3203 \\
\% of correct predictions & 84.01 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}}

\noindent
Robust standard errors in brackets.\\
*** $p<0.01$, ** $p<0.05$, * $p<0.1$\\
Authors’ estimations using 2006 QUIBB survey.

\noindent
\textbf{Note}: For the impact analysis, the sample is restricted to
 the relevant geographic area. i.e. only the PSU with at least one 
 household who have benefited from the WFP transfer

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, the noindent looks better, but the attached text is on the next page. I think I may have to pick between the lesser of two evils.

Comment: @PaulKlassen It isn't on the next page in the code as posted (it always helps if you post complete documents not just fragments) there is no flexibility in table rows so if the page break happens at the table end before the note, you can't easily avoid that, you could put in a forced break to force the last few rows to come over the page, or you could `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}` so it all stretches out a bit and the page break happens in a different place or ...

Comment: I see there is no easy/elegant solution. I will experiment with the options, and try to find something that looks good now and will still look good after the client has made changes that affect the placement of the table. This document, incidentally, in addition to being very long, is not my intellectual property, so am reluctant to post the whole thing … but I see your point.